# Where can one find the Bitcoin core roadmap?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Is there a site where it shows the current Bitcoin core roadmap on what features will be implemented in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://bitcoincore.org

It contains plans for [releases](https://bitcoincore.org/en/lifecycle/), features (sometimes ) announced on the [blog](https://bitcoincore.org/en/blog/), [IRC meeting notes](https://bitcoincore.org/en/meetings/) and you can also subscribe to announcements here: https://bitcoincore.org/en/list/announcements/join/. Note that if you want to see which issues and PR's are scheduled for the next release, you can search by milestone. Eg. `is:open is:pr milestone:0.17.0`

Potentially the most up to date (and accurate) would be the [Bitcoin Github Repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin). Potential features and bugs can be found on the [Issues](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues) page as well, and code that is proposed for merging on the [Pull Requests](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pulls) page. It will usually also include comments from collaborators that can give an idea of when it might be implemented.